# ¿ Como crear el logo para mi web?

Tags: html, css

Estoy tratando de crear un logo para mi web pero solo consigo el resultado que veras en la parte de abajo.
Quiero meter ese logo en la barra de navegación y que no aparezca el icono que se ve a la izquierda de mi nombre.
Seguro que  estoy haciendo mal el logo, ¿ que forma hay de hacerlo ? .
Si alguien puede ayudarme a como meter ese logo en la barra de navegación.
Gracias, me código no ayuda mucho imagino.

```css
/* LA VERDAD ES QUE FUNCIONA CASI TODO GRACIAS A LOS RETOQUES DE Camilo Vasquez, Alvaro Montoro*/
html, body {
    height:100%;
    margin:0px;
    color:#444444;
    -ms-text-size-adjust:100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;
    font:400 16px/1.8 sans-serif;
    }
    
    .nav-navbar-nav{
        font-size: 5;
    
    }
    .bgimg-1, .bgimg-2, .bgimg-3 {
    position:relative;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-position:center;
    background-size:cover;
    }
    .bgimg-1 {
    background-image:url("../imagenes/bg_01.jpg");
    height:100%;
    }
    .bgimg-2 {
    background-image:url("../imagenes/bg_02.jpg");
    height:100%;
    }
    .bgimg-3 {
    background-image:url("../imagenes/bg_03.jpg");
    height:100%;
    }
    .caption {
    position:absolute;
    left:10%;
    top:48%;
    width:80%;
    margin:auto;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-size:24px;
    text-align:center;
    letter-spacing:10px;
    background-color:#444444;
    }
    h2 {
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font:20px sans-serif;
    letter-spacing:4px;
    color:#444444;
    }
    a {
    text-decoration:none;
    letter-spacing:3px;
    }
    .navbar-nav{
      margin-left: 5% !important;
    }
    
    #center{
      padding-right:2%;
   }

    #header{
      position: fixed;
      width: 100%;
      z-index: 1000;
      font-size: 6
    }
    
    .navbar{
      margin-bottom: 0px !important;
    }

    .navbar ul li a{
      font-size: 12px
    }

    .col-md-6{
      padding-left: 5%;
    }

    .col-md-6{
      padding-right: 5%;
    }
    /* LA VERDAD ES QUE FUNCIONA CASI TODO GRACIAS A LOS RETOQUES DE Camilo Vasquez, Alvaro Montoro*/


/*codigo nuevo*/

.buscar {
position: absolute;
width: 40px;
height: 100%;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: flex-end;
right: 0px;
transition: all .3s ease;
z-index: 100;
  }
  
  .buscar input {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
padding:10px;
  }
  
  .buscar span {
position: absolute;
right: 0px;
padding: 15px;
background: rgb(245, 245, 245);
  }
  
  .buscar span img {
width: 18px
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <title>PRINCIPAL</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    <!-- ESTOS ENLACES LES TENGO GRACIAS A Camilo Vasquez me sugirio para crear barra de navegacion-->
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="css/todo.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/busqueda.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--<style> 
        input[type=text] {
            width: 130px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            border: 2px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 4px;
            font-size: 16px;
            background-color: white;
            background-image: url('#');
            background-position: 10px 10px; 
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            padding: 3px 20px 12px 40px;
            -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
            transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
        }
        
        input[type=text]:focus {
            width: 50%;
        }
        </style>-->
</head>
<!-- AQUI TAMBIEN FORMO PARTE Camilo Vasquez AYUDANDO ME CON LOS BOTONES DE LA BARRA DE NAVEGACION-->
<body>
    <header id="header">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
          <div class="container">
            <!-- Logo and responsive toggle -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
    
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></span>
                <img src="http://i64.tinypic.com/32zsuqf.png" ></a>
              <!-- codigo Nuevo -->
              <div class="buscar">
                <span id="buscar">
                  <img src="http://svgshare.com/i/42h.svg"> </span>
                <input placeholder="Buscar" type="text" name="" value="">
              </div>
              <!-- codigo Nuevo -->
            </div>
                <!-- Navbar links -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active">
                            <a href="#">PRINCIPAL</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a target"_blank" href="Contacto.html">CONTACTO</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">TUTORIALES</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">SOBRE MI
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li>
                                    <a target="_blank" href="curriculum.html">CURRICULUM</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    
                                    <a target="_blank" href="proyectos.html">LOGROS</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Diseño</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- busqueda -->
                    <!--<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Buscar</button>
                    </form>-->
                    <form>
                        <!--<input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Buscar...">-->
                      </form>

                </div>
                <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.container -->
        </nav>
    </header>

    <!-- AKI EMPIEZA ELCONDUMIO-->


    <div class="bgimg-1">
        <div class="caption">
            <span>CREAMOS LA APLICACION QUE NECESITE PARA SU NEGOCIO</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="color:#444444;background-color:#FFFFFF;text-align:center;padding:48px 80px;text-align:justify;">
        <h2 style="text-align:center;">CURRICULUM</h2>
        <h1>BIENVENIDOS A MI SITIO WEB...</h1>
        <p>Hola, me llamo Miguel y os voy a presentar mi sitio web, el cual estoy creando mientras realizo un curso de actívate. 
         En principio esta creado para mostrar mi perfil, experiencia laboral, formación académica y todos los conocimientos que 
         vaya adquiriendo en el curso. </p>
    </div>

    <div class="bgimg-2">
        <div class="caption">
            <span>EMPEZANDO EN DESARROLLO WEB</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="position:relative;">
        <div style="color:#FFFFFF;background-color:#444444;text-align:center;padding:48px 80px;text-align:justify;">
            <p>ESTO IRA MEJORANDOSE, SEGUN VAYA EXPERIMENTANDO</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="bgimg-3">
        <div class="caption">
            <span>MAS IMAGENES</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="position:relative;">
        <div style="color:#444444;background-color:#FFFFFF;text-align:center;padding:48px 80px;text-align:justify;">
            <p>AQUI PONDRE IMAGENES, CUANDO VAYA APRENDIENDO</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="bgimg-1">
        <div class="caption">
            <span>¡DIVERTIDO, EH!</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var activo = false
        $("#buscar").click(function () {
          if (!activo) {
            $(this).parent("div").css({
              "width": "100%"
            });
            $(this).find("img").attr("src", "http://svgshare.com/i/44D.svg")
    
          } else {
            $(this).parent("div").css({
              "width": "40px"
            });
            $(this).find("img").attr("src", "http://svgshare.com/i/42h.svg")
          }
          activo = !activo
        })
      </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplemente añádele una altura a tu imagen y borra la llama que tienes actualmente.

En el CSS:

```
#logo{
   height: 21px;
}
```

Tu ejemplo modificado:

```css
/* LA VERDAD ES QUE FUNCIONA CASI TODO GRACIAS A LOS RETOQUES DE Camilo Vasquez, Alvaro Montoro*/
html, body {
    height:100%;
    margin:0px;
    color:#444444;
    -ms-text-size-adjust:100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;
    font:400 16px/1.8 sans-serif;
    }
    
    .nav-navbar-nav{
        font-size: 5;
    
    }
    .bgimg-1, .bgimg-2, .bgimg-3 {
    position:relative;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-position:center;
    background-size:cover;
    }
    .bgimg-1 {
    background-image:url("../imagenes/bg_01.jpg");
    height:100%;
    }
    .bgimg-2 {
    background-image:url("../imagenes/bg_02.jpg");
    height:100%;
    }
    .bgimg-3 {
    background-image:url("../imagenes/bg_03.jpg");
    height:100%;
    }
    .caption {
    position:absolute;
    left:10%;
    top:48%;
    width:80%;
    margin:auto;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-size:24px;
    text-align:center;
    letter-spacing:10px;
    background-color:#444444;
    }
    h2 {
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font:20px sans-serif;
    letter-spacing:4px;
    color:#444444;
    }
    a {
    text-decoration:none;
    letter-spacing:3px;
    }
    .navbar-nav{
      margin-left: 5% !important;
    }
    
    #center{
      padding-right:2%;
   }

    #header{
      position: fixed;
      width: 100%;
      z-index: 1000;
      font-size: 6
    }
    
    .navbar{
      margin-bottom: 0px !important;
    }

    .navbar ul li a{
      font-size: 12px
    }

    .col-md-6{
      padding-left: 5%;
    }

    .col-md-6{
      padding-right: 5%;
    }
    /* LA VERDAD ES QUE FUNCIONA CASI TODO GRACIAS A LOS RETOQUES DE Camilo Vasquez, Alvaro Montoro*/


/*codigo nuevo*/

.buscar {
position: absolute;
width: 40px;
height: 100%;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: flex-end;
right: 0px;
transition: all .3s ease;
z-index: 100;
  }
  
  .buscar input {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
padding:10px;
  }
  
  .buscar span {
position: absolute;
right: 0px;
padding: 15px;
background: rgb(245, 245, 245);
  }
  
  .buscar span img {
width: 18px
  }
  
  #logo{
    height: 21px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <title>PRINCIPAL</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    <!-- ESTOS ENLACES LES TENGO GRACIAS A Camilo Vasquez me sugirio para crear barra de navegacion-->
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="css/todo.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/busqueda.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--<style> 
        input[type=text] {
            width: 130px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            border: 2px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 4px;
            font-size: 16px;
            background-color: white;
            background-image: url('#');
            background-position: 10px 10px; 
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            padding: 3px 20px 12px 40px;
            -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
            transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
        }
        
        input[type=text]:focus {
            width: 50%;
        }
        </style>-->
</head>
<!-- AQUI TAMBIEN FORMO PARTE Camilo Vasquez AYUDANDO ME CON LOS BOTONES DE LA BARRA DE NAVEGACION-->
<body>
    <header id="header">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
          <div class="container">
            <!-- Logo and responsive toggle -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
    
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <!-- ********* ELIMINAR ****** -->
                <!--<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></span>-->
                <img id="logo" src="http://i64.tinypic.com/32zsuqf.png" ></a>
              <!-- codigo Nuevo -->
              <div class="buscar">
                <span id="buscar">
                  <img src="http://svgshare.com/i/42h.svg"> </span>
                <input placeholder="Buscar" type="text" name="" value="">
              </div>
              <!-- codigo Nuevo -->
            </div>
                <!-- Navbar links -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active">
                            <a href="#">PRINCIPAL</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a target"_blank" href="Contacto.html">CONTACTO</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">TUTORIALES</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">SOBRE MI
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li>
                                    <a target="_blank" href="curriculum.html">CURRICULUM</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    
                                    <a target="_blank" href="proyectos.html">LOGROS</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Diseño</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- busqueda -->
                    <!--<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Buscar</button>
                    </form>-->
                    <form>
                        <!--<input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Buscar...">-->
                      </form>

                </div>
                <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.container -->
        </nav>
    </header>

    <!-- AKI EMPIEZA ELCONDUMIO-->


    <div class="bgimg-1">
        <div class="caption">
            <span>CREAMOS LA APLICACION QUE NECESITE PARA SU NEGOCIO</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="color:#444444;background-color:#FFFFFF;text-align:center;padding:48px 80px;text-align:justify;">
        <h2 style="text-align:center;">CURRICULUM</h2>
        <h1>BIENVENIDOS A MI SITIO WEB...</h1>
        <p>Hola, me llamo Miguel y os voy a presentar mi sitio web, el cual estoy creando mientras realizo un curso de actívate. 
         En principio esta creado para mostrar mi perfil, experiencia laboral, formación académica y todos los conocimientos que 
         vaya adquiriendo en el curso. </p>
    </div>

    <div class="bgimg-2">
        <div class="caption">
            <span>EMPEZANDO EN DESARROLLO WEB</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="position:relative;">
        <div style="color:#FFFFFF;background-color:#444444;text-align:center;padding:48px 80px;text-align:justify;">
            <p>ESTO IRA MEJORANDOSE, SEGUN VAYA EXPERIMENTANDO</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="bgimg-3">
        <div class="caption">
            <span>MAS IMAGENES</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="position:relative;">
        <div style="color:#444444;background-color:#FFFFFF;text-align:center;padding:48px 80px;text-align:justify;">
            <p>AQUI PONDRE IMAGENES, CUANDO VAYA APRENDIENDO</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="bgimg-1">
        <div class="caption">
            <span>¡DIVERTIDO, EH!</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var activo = false
        $("#buscar").click(function () {
          if (!activo) {
            $(this).parent("div").css({
              "width": "100%"
            });
            $(this).find("img").attr("src", "http://svgshare.com/i/44D.svg")
    
          } else {
            $(this).parent("div").css({
              "width": "40px"
            });
            $(this).find("img").attr("src", "http://svgshare.com/i/42h.svg")
          }
          activo = !activo
        })
      </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, Ya he eliminado las llamas, ¿ pero no hay manera de eliminar el fondo del logo para que queden las letras sobre la barra de navegación como el resto de recursos: Principal, Contacto...? Gracias.

Comment: @MiguelEspeso Ese fondo por lo que veo viene de la imagen, por lo que no lo podrás modificar con CSS. Necesitarás usar algún editor de imágenes y hacer el fondo transparente. Entiendo que con la frase `para que queden las letras sobre la barra de navegación como el resto de recursos` te refieres a que detrás de las letras no existe ese fondo.

Comment: Gracias, tratare de solucionarlo.

Comment: Es algo tarde para comentar, pero como estás aprendiendo creo que es bueno entre más sepas, lo cierto es que para **eliminar fondos de imagenes en código no se puede**, tienes que emplear photoshop, sin embargo hay trucos en CSS3 que podrían ayudarte por ejemplo en tu ejemplo **a la imagen agregale mix-blend-mode: screen.** Este modo de fusión **"screen"** transparentará lo negro u oscuro de una foto contrario a **"multiply"** que hará transparente lo blanco o color claro. Éxitos!